# Pandas : Optimizing, deleting a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a set of data which i need to clean, around **400.000 lines**.

Two actions to make:

1. Resale Invoice Month are objects `'M201705'`. I want to make a column named `'Year'` with only the year in that case `2017`.
2. Some commercial products which are objects also, end with `'TR'`. I want **to delete the TR** from these products. For example for `'M23065TR'` I want to change all the products in to `'M23065'`, but in the column there are also products names which are already good, like `'M340767'` or `'M34TR32'`, which should remain unchanged.

You can find my try below:

```py
#First case
for i in range(Ndata.shape[0]):    
    Ndata['Year'][i] = str(Ndata['Resale Invoice Month'][i])[1:5]
#A loop takes too much time
#Tried that also : 
NData['Year'] = Ndata.str['Resale Invoice Month'][1:5]
#Error : Str is not an attribute of dataframe

for i in range(Ndata.shape[0]):
    if (Ndata['Commercial Product Code'][i][-2:]=='TR')==True:
        Ndata.loc[i,'Commercial Product Code']=Ndata.loc[i,'Commercial Product Code'][:-2]
#same issue is a loop

#I was advice to do that : 
idx = Ndata[Ndata['Commercial Product Code'].str[-2:]=='TR']
Ndata.loc[idx, 'Commercial Product Code'] = Ndata[idx]['Commercial Product Code'].str[:-2]
#It doesn't work as well
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the year as characters 1-4 use `Series.str[indices]`:

```
Ndata['Year'] = Ndata['Resale Invoice Month'].str[1:5]
```

To remove 'TR' from the end of the string use `Series.str.replace`. Here `$` matches the end of the string:

```
Ndata['Commercial Product Code'] = Ndata['Commercial Product Code'].str.replace('TR$', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
# get the 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th characters of Ndata[Resale Invoice Month]

Ndata['Year'] = Ndata['Resale Invoice Month'].str[1:5].astype(int)

# remove the last two characters if they are TR

Ndata.loc[Ndata['Commercial Product Code'].str[-2:] == 'TR', 'Commercial Product Code'] = Ndata['Commercial Product Code'].str[:-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe a one-liner using `replace` with `regex=True`:

```
Ndata['Year'] = Ndata['Resale Invoice Month'].str[1:5].replace('TR', '', regex=True)
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Would be as expected.